How to apply Bonferroni correction method in step-wise selection process?
Let me provide the question in an easily understandable example for clarity.
I have 4 phenotypes (response variables) and hence 4 different models. Each model is passed through a step-wise selection process separately to select the most important model components. Assume we have selected 3 independent variables in model 1, 5 independent variables in model 2, 2 independent variables in model 3 and 5 independent variables in model 4 respectively, out of 10 (common) independent variables.

When I apply Bonferroni correction on this whole setting, do I need to divide alpha (significance level) by 4 or 10 or 4*10=40 or any other number? Why?

Please provide references on applying such Bonferroni correction method on step-wise regression models.

In this case, can I argue that Bonferroni correction is not necessary as it is filtered already from the selection procedure and hence, unlikely to have false positives?


Please advise.

I’m afraid that you have this backwards. Stepwise predictor selection doesn’t protect you from false positives. It is likely to overfit the data and give erroneously low p-values. See this page for why stepwise and other automated model selection methods aren’t good ideas. So there really is no good way to combine stepwise selection with multiple-comparison correction.
It sounds like there might be a better way to analyze your data, anyway. If the 4 phenotypes are mutually exclusive, for example, a single multinomial regression model might be highly preferable. I’d suggest that you post a new question more specifically describing your data and what you are trying to learn from them. You might get some valuable suggestions.

Thanks for the answer. Imagine, I somehow did step-wise selection, and now I need to control FDR by using Bonferroni correction. Just to be clear, does this answer mean that applying Bonferroni correction to step-wise regression result (model) is undefined? I understood the rest of the points in this answer, and thank you.
